# Организация таблиц идентификаторов

Tags: c++

задание такое:
написать программу,
которая получает на входе набор идентификаторов, организует таблицы
идентификаторов с помощью заданных методов, позволяет осуществить
многократный поиск произвольного идентификатора в таблицах и сравнить
эффективность методов организации таблиц. Список идентификаторов
считать заданным в виде текстового файла. Длина идентификаторов
ограничена 32 символами. Метод 1 таблицы цепочка вторая таблица список, Ребят это странно звучит но я не могу понять как это реализовать звучит очень сложно, 20 раз уже методичку перечитал толку ноль а код даже показать уже не приятно ибо он совсем не то то что надо. Прошу помогите понять как это сделать я не прошу готовы код хочу сам понять может какие то примеры приведёте.

Comment: Видимо, от вас хотят несколько реализаций таблиц, сами же пишете — обычный массив, список. Я бы еще хеш-таблицу задал :) И сравнить их эффективность.

Comment: в этом и проблема понять как бы я понял, но вот реализовать уже дело другое

Comment: Ну берите готовые `vector`, `list`, если свое не пишется...